# Android In App Products have disappeared in my App (They still exist on the developer console)

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I've been developing an app which uses in app purchases. I'd been successfully querying the Google Play app with the SKUs in my app, getting prices and descriptions back etc.

I was attempting to setup the next stage (Actually buying the in app products) and deployed a new APK file up to the Google Play store (Not published) and the SKUs stopped being returned for my In App Purchases.

Does anyone have any idea why they would disappear from my App? Or how to get them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was just a matter of being patient.  After uploading the APK file the IAPs disappeared, but have come back without me changing anything...